# Fontello and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, fontello

There are some strange fact, when I use Fontello with jQuery.

If I add some div

```
<div class="qwerty" style="display: none;">
        <i class="icon-move"></i>
</div>
```

and if I try to clone `<i>`  element like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var cl = $(".icon-move").clone();
            $(cl).css("display", "block");
            $(cl).appendTo(".content-wrapper");

});
```

it clones OK.

But if I try to create new `<i>` element in DOM with jQuery and append new `<i>` element to the some `<div>` element like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var i = $("<i>");
            $(i).appendTo(".content-wrapper");
});
```

then `<i>` element will be added, but this `<i class="icon-move"></i>` not show as fontello picture.

Can I create new `<i>` elements in DOM `<i class="icon-move"></i>` for fontello? Why not?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like you didn't add the class to the `<i>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make the code look like

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var i = $("<i>");
            $(i).addClass("icon-move");
            $(i).appendTo(".content-wrapper");
        })
</script>
```